# Atom Feed shows header but no posts

Tags: php, simplepie

http://businessuites.forumatic.com/feed.php

Any thoughts on this? (feeds/php is the folder in relation to where the main file is loaded)

```
// simple rss/atom feed reader
require_once('feeds/php/autoloader.php');

// Single feed
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url('http://businessuites.forumatic.com/feed.php');
$feed->enable_order_by_date(false);
$feed->set_cache_location($cachepath . '/cache');
$feed->init();
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items(0, 5) as $item):
    ?>
<div class="item">
<h2>xxx<a href="<?php echo $item->get_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></a></h2>
<p><?php echo $item->get_description(); ?></p>
<p><small>Posted on <?php echo $item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?></small></p>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the article content, use

```
$item->get_content();
```

instead of

```
$item->get_description();
```

The feed you listed also does not have any articles. If you paste it directly in your browser you will see the feed page with no content.